# Design pattern for different kinds of format

Tags: design-patterns

I'm implementing the exporting feature for my project.
I have a question about design pattern .

What is the best pattern for implementing a feature that allows exporting from database to different kind of format(i.e. plain text, CSV, XML, PDF...).?

In my case, I have to choose among Template Method, Proxy and Observer. Which should i choose?

Thank you

Comment: given that PDF v.s. TXT is about as similar as an elephant and a mars rover, your pattern would have to be so extraordinarly generalized it'd be next to useless.

Comment: "In my case, I have to choose among Template Method, Proxy and Observer. Which should i choose?" Why only those choices? Is this a homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are (potentially) looking for the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

> whereby an algorithm's behaviour can be selected at runtime

Essentially you might have something like an `IExporter`, then multiple implimentations `XmlExporter`, `PlainTextExporter` etc. then at run time you could select one or more of the to actually execute, the execution call would be the same but the result would be different.

Like:

```
public abstract class ExporterBase
{
    abstract public bool Export(Record record);
}

public class DatabaseExporter : ExporterBase
{
  public bool Export(Record record) 
  {
    // TODO: Write to DB
     return true;
  }
}

public class CsvExporter : ExporterBase
{
  public bool Export(Record record) 
  {
    // TODO: Write to Csv file
     return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a limitation in this approach because in abstract function, you assume that, all exporter formats come from a specific type Record.     
In practical, it hardly happens.